# I am getting this error with this code for edited method

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent, model, controller

[image]
I am getting this error with this code for edited method

Comment: Please. no images (or links to them.) Copy-and-paste your code, and the error message.

Comment: What error? What code? Why sql? What are you attempting? We are not mind readers, you need to give us some information if you want our help